# Finding lat/lng weighted midpoint from a list of points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I am a truck driver and I have an historical list of `cities, lat/lng, count` where count is the number of times that I've made a delivery in that specific location.

I want to find the **optimal location** (lat,lng) where I should live, considering the history in this list. So that I'd be in a (statistically) good position for my usual work, should it not change too much in the future.

I've found this link, that explain the **geographic weighted midpoint** http://www.geomidpoint.com/calculation.html and it looks fine but maybe there are better approaches that I'm not aware of.

1. Is it a correct approach considering that I don't need road distances? (working on the sphere distance is good enough)
2. Is there an easy way to import such a CSV file into QGIS and find some kind of weighted  midpoint without relying on my terrible math skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to import the CSV and give it which fields are x and y co-ordinates and the projection of your data. This should be the large comma icon which says `Add Delimited Text Layer`.

If you then go to the Vector menu (you may need the Ftools plugin installed but this comes as standard in recent versions of QGIS I believe) then Analysis, you have a menu item `Mean Co-ordinate(s)`. You should click on this. You should get a dialog box as follows:
[image]

You can select the layer you just added for the `Input vector layer` option, the field which has the number of times you visited that city as the `Weight field`. You should leave the `Unique ID field` blank and then chose where you want to save the new shapefile.

I don't know how this will work for lat long data as it may get skewed depending on where you are in the world. I would use a projected co-ordinate system, although possibly QGIS does all those calculations for you.

This seems like a good little tool, thanks for making me experiment!